# Can I reread acquired text logs in Dead Space?

Tags: dead-space

And if so, how?

I think I clicked to eagerly when I picked up a text log, and as a result, I didn’t read it. Dead Space’s interface is quite convoluted, so there might be an archive there somewhere.

“No” is an acceptable answer, too, as I just need to know whether there actually is an archive or not.

Comment: I think you can, but I can't remember right now how to do it. I'll boot it up tonight and see if I can find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can.
Enter the RIG system and hit the right bumper till you get to the DATABASE.

[image]

They should all be there arranged by chapter.
You may need to scroll down to see more. They are aranged by type and will appear as though there are blank spaces in the list till you find everything.